# JSF 2.0 and Facelets

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets, jsf-2

In blogs i have read that JSF 2.0 is inlcuding Facelets. So i only included `JSF-api.jar` and `JSF-impl.jar` to my Java build path.

But if i try to use Facelet tags, they don't work. Do i need to configure Facelets anywhere or must i include any further libraries?

THX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should works fine. More information and working example you can find in IBM developer works [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu1/index.html) and following articles in [this series](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/java/libraryview.jsp?search_by=JSF+2+fu).

Answer (score 3):

How to configure/use Facelets is outlined the Java EE 6 tutorial: [Developing a Simple Facelets Application](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/gipob.html) (also check the subsequent pages). You're likely forgotten to declare the `ui` taglib.

Comment: +1 The Java EE 6 tutorial actually makes this stuff quite clear. (Unlike e.g. some documentation under facelets.dev.java.net)

Answer (score 0):

Install Facelets as in article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/#install

download jar from http://download.java.net/maven/1/com.sun.facelets/jars/

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify tag libraries in the html tag?
Like:

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
......
</html>
```