# icefaces-facelets.jar Where is it on IceFaces 2?

Tags: facelets, icefaces, icefaces-2

Does anyone know where can i get the icefaces-facelets.jar do i have to downloads the 1.8 specification? is it compatible?

Answer (score 1):

Use default `facelets` for your configuration. IceFaces do not have its own anymore and they started to use the default instead. So in pom.xml you could have for example:

> ```
>   <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
>         <version>1.1.10</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

With icefaces 2 you don't need the icefaces-facelets.jar anymore. Depending on your coding you need the icefaces.jar and the icefaces-compat.jar or even the new icefaces-ace.jar.

Answer (score 0):

icefaces 2.0 is based on jsf 2.0, which comes already with facelets, so you don't need any facelets jar. You can find more info in this SO question:

[JSF 2.0 and Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939577/jsf-2-0-and-facelets)